# Are there any html5 .Net binding frameworks

Tags: c#, html, xaml, frameworks

Since we now have wpf and xaml to separate out the ui from the view/models.  And since we now have things like knockoutjs to do viewmodel bindings for javascript.

Is there something out there that allows for things like the trident engine to interface with c# to do view model binding to a html5 page...

I guess this question is two part.  Is there a way to bind c# to a dom the same way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

is, perhaps we can have a

```
   <script type="text/csharp" src="app.dll">
    <script type="text/csharp">
      using Browser;
      ...
```

perhaps create a plugin for Trident/Webkit/etc. which can compile it and execute it on the fly.

Part two would be the same way xulrunner runs which can make html5 page into a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)! from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com)! for HTML5 + .Net frameworks.